# How to make disabled inputs editable after clicking edit button

Tags: vue.js, pug

How can I make these inputs editable after being clicked Edit button using vuejs?

```
form
  .form-group
    label(for='exampleInputEmail1') Email address
    input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='jan.kowalski@poczta.pl', readonly='')
  .form-group
    label(for='exampleInputEmail1') Name
    input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Jan', readonly='')
  .form-group
    label(for='exampleInputEmail1') Surname
    input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Kowalski', readonly='')    
  .form-group
    label(for='exampleInputPassword1') Password
    input.form-control(type='password', placeholder='*********', readonly='')
  .form-group
    label(for='exampleInputPassword1') Password
    input.form-control(type='password', placeholder='*********', readonly='')
  .form-group
    a.btn.btn-primary.btn-blood.btn-main
      | Edit
```

Comment: Start [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) and read up on how "event handling" works in Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use the `readonly` attribute, use `:disabled` and set it's value to some variable. That variable will need to be true intially, but have the button press change it to false.

As an example, your pug would look like

```
form
  .form-group
    label(for='exampleInputEmail1') Email address
    input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='jan.kowalski@poczta.pl', :disabled='notYetClicked')
  .form-group
    label(for='exampleInputEmail1') Name
    input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Jan', :disabled='notYetClicked')
  .form-group
    label(for='exampleInputEmail1') Surname
    input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Kowalski', :disabled='notYetClicked')    
  .form-group
    label(for='exampleInputPassword1') Password
    input.form-control(type='password', placeholder='*********', :disabled='notYetClicked')
  .form-group
    label(for='exampleInputPassword1') Password
    input.form-control(type='password', placeholder='*********', :disabled='notYetClicked')
  .form-group
    a.btn.btn-primary.btn-blood.btn-main(v-on:click='notYetClicked = false')
      | Edit
```

and add the new variable to your JS

```js
export default {
  name: 'item-list',

  data() {
    return {
      notYetClicked: true,
    }
  },
}
```